# Use array of strings in React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

In a form that I am making the material that is being created in the form should have multiple width options that can be added. This means that I will have a text input where the user can add an option, and when this option is added, it should be added to the React Hook Form `widthOptions` array, without using the regular react state. How would one do this? How do you add an item to the total React Hook Form state, I only see options for just one input field corresponding to a property.

This is how i would do it using the regular React state

```
import { TrashIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [widthOptions, setWidthOptions] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const removeWidthOption = (widthOption: string) => {
    setWidthOptions(widthOptions.filter((option) => option !== widthOption));
  };

  const addWidthOption = (widthOption: string) => {
    setWidthOptions([...widthOptions, widthOption]);
  };

  const editWidthOptions = (widthOption: string, index: number) => {
    const newWidthOptions = [...widthOptions];
    newWidthOptions[index] = widthOption;
    setWidthOptions(newWidthOptions);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={() => addWidthOption(inputRef?.current?.value)}>
        Add Width Option
      </button>
      {widthOptions.map((option, index) => (
        <div className="flex">
          <input
            type="text"
            value={option}
            onChange={() => editWidthOptions(option, index)}
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={() => removeWidthOption(option)}>
            <TrashIcon className="w-5 h-5 mb-3 text-gray-500" />
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just the controller component for this as for all other fields.
Since you have not shared any of you code here is a generic multi-select

```js
<Controller
  name={name}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange, ref } }) => {
    return (
    // You can use whatever component you want here, the you get the value from the form and use onChange to update the value as you would with a regular state
      <Test
        widthOptions={value}
        setWidthOptions={onChange}
      />
    );
  }}
/>;
```

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/

And in you Test component remove the state and get the props instead

```js
const Test = ({widthOptions, setWidthOptions}) => {
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Ok, and what needs to be done in the onChange? How do i refer to the state of the field / form?

Comment: React hook form hold the state, `name` acts as the key. 
onChange just take any value and set it as the new value of the `name`.
This is basically the same as what I have in the example above `onChange={(newArray: string[])=>onChange(newArray)}`
If you need further assistance you will have to updated your question with the code you need help with.

Comment: I have added an example of what i want, using regular React state

Comment: @Bowis great job on the component, I have updated my answer. As you can see you can just replace the state with props.